# How can I share assembly references between Autofac modules

Tags: c#, .net, module, .net-assembly, autofac

In my applications I will usually have multiple autofac modules and many of them will perform some work retrieving assembly references, e.g. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` or `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyRef)` etc. Often different modules will retrieve the same assemblies, so assuming that there is an overhead in the reflection is there anyway to share the assembly references between modules to make this more efficient?

For example, would it be appropriate to create static references to the assemblies in the root of the application so they can be referenced by each of the modules? This seems a bit overkill if the sole purpose of using them is for the registration process.

Alternatively, am I trying to optimize something that doesn't need to be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little overhead in the reflection across assemblies - it's not the way it used to be in .NET 1.1. Especially in the sense of the one-time hit of registration at app startup, you're treading into the territory of micro optimization.

If you're concerned about the reflection perf, I'd encourage you to actually measure it, then try doing some sort of additional reference caching and see the difference. I'd bet you don't actually see significant savings - not enough to justify the additional application complexity and tighter coupling, anyhow.

One thing you *can* do that's pretty simple is just add a constructor to your modules that takes in the list of assemblies it should use.

```
public class ScanningModule : Module
{
  private IEnumerable<Assembly> _assemblies;
  public ScanningModule(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
  {
    this._assemblies = assemblies;
  }

  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this._assemblies)...
  }
}
```

When you register the module, pass in the assemblies to it.

```
var assemblies = ScanForTheAssemblies();
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ScanningModule(assemblies));
...
var container = builder.Build();
```

However, again, I'm not sure you're going to see a major perf increase, especially since it only happens once.